# OS Upgrade Path for DB and Application

Tags: mysql, database-design, ubuntu

Are there any best practices which define which Operating System Upgrade Path we should choose and any rational behind it?

Path 1: Upgrade Database OS then Upgrade Application OS.

Path 2: Upgrade Application OS and then Upgrade DB OS.

Comment: creating a testing environment clone of both of these and test. After upgrade, test the full functionality of the application. When you have a list of changes, rehearse the change again.

Comment: due to infra constrains even for POC server, we cannot test these two paths, we need to decide strategy based on industry best practices.

Comment: industry best practices is to work out how to afford a temporary server instead of potentially loosing data, completing and almost impossible DB downgrade, or spending many many hours of downtime fixing things that should have been found in a test environment. After all its just a VM and a restore of a backup? Which you have right? because industry best practices are important to you.

Comment: The industry best practice is to have enough spare infrastructure that you can do testing. Too much economy is not economical.

Answer (score 1):

You don't upgrade an OS or a RDBMS version. The safest thing to do is to prepare a new server with latest OS and latest RDBMS version and migrate everything to that server so in case there are problems you can rollback.

Here the steps:

1. You have Server PROD and you create a server called Server TEST running the latest OS version, the latest RDBMS version and the latest Application version.
2. You now migrate a copy of your PROD to the server TEST and you test if OS, RDBMS and Application are working fine for you. Here you can also test how to migrate: do you want to take a backup of the database and export? How much downtime this will create? Can we ship the logs or have a mirrored copy instead and reduce the downtime of the migrations?
3. Now that you have checked that everything runs smoothy you have to create a new server that will be your new production server and you will call it Server PROD 2023
4. You now migrate everything to your new server which will be your new production server

Are you encountering problems in your new Server PROD 2023?

Roll back and point your application to the previous Server PROD and everything will work like before.